# Listview axis horizontal not show widget

Tags: flutter, dart

When I change axis direction to horizontal, widgets disappears from screen.

In vertical mode works fine, show all widgets.

Thanks for helping!)

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.385,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: About(),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
                child: About(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: For me it works with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`. How does your `About` widget look like?

Comment: There are disappeared from the screen.

Comment: Replacing `About()` with `Text("text")` for me shows correct horizontal `ListView`. Maybe your `About` widget is the problem, that's why I asked to show how it looks like.

Comment: You right, in About widget width set to double.infinity. Thanks a lot!)

Comment: You are welcome.